# Are there tests available to test Unicode-related algorithms?

Tags: string, unit-testing, testing, text, unicode

I wonder if there is something like "official conformance tests" from the Unicode consortium (or a related organization) which enables testing and verification of text-related algorithms and implementations.

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The UCD contains a number of [test data files](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Test_Files). Those provide data in standard formats which can be used to test implementations of Unicode algorithms.

You can get the latest version of the Unicode Character Database [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/).

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are many, just get them from inside [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

I just hope that you were interested about C/C++ or Java :)